# CPU takes too much time to execute nested for loop in Linux compare to windows platform

Tags: c, linux, windows

I am going to run one nested for loop in my Linux Platform which takes around 55 milliseconds and same program can be run on windows which takes around 25 milliseconds.

The CPU configuration in both Linux and Windows platform is almost same as compare to CPU clock and RAM.

I have also attached the code in this question.

SO, does anyone have idea about what is going on here or how to optimize this nested for loop which i am going to run on this Linux PC?

```
for (i = 0; i < 1944; i += 2)
        for (j = 0; j < 2592; j += 2)
          {
             Here some arithmetic operation is going on
          }
```

Comment: 1. We need the "some arithmetic operation". 2. We need the compiler names you're using and the parameters you use to invoke them. 3. We need the code you use to profile your code, to verify it's accuracy.

Comment: Unless you provide the math and/or the scripts used to make the performance tests, how can anyone help you?

Comment: "Linux" and "Windows" are not the names of C compilers that I have ever heard of. "The CPU configuration in both Linux and Windows platform is almost same" -- *almost* the same?

Comment: Means, The Hardware configuration like CPU clock and RAM are same in bth linux and windows based PC.

Comment: "almost" does not mean "the same". But regardless, please read the comments and the answer below and consider why your question has been downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the support to discuss this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Linux versus Windows is almost certainly irrelevant in this case.  Are you

- Using the same compiler on both platforms?
- Using the same version of the compiler on both platforms?
- Using the same optimization settings on both platforms?

All of these will cause the result to be different.  Furthermore, it is not even specified if the CPUs are identical.  Benchmarking my audio sample rate conversion library, I clocked a 6-7x difference in throughput between a 1.7 GHz Core i5 and a 1.6 GHz Atom.

- Are you using the *same hardware* for both benchmarks?

There are a number of other factors which confound benchmarks,

- Are you running other processes in the background?
- Are you using the same technique to measure performance in both cases?
- Have you collected enough samples (and have you done the math to prove it)?

Comment: Consider adding: Is he measuring the performance in a comparable way? What are the errors of measurement? How many measurements were conducted and have you performed a statistical comparison like a student-t test or a chi-square test?

Comment: The compiler in windows is vc++ compiler while in linux is gcc compiler.

Comment: Yes. I am using the same hardware on both platform and i have also compiled one sample binary based on that code which takes 55 milliseconds on linux and 25 milliseconds on windows platform. I am not running any other processes on background.

Comment: I got the solution of the above issue from our side in linux

Comment: thanks for the support to discuss the issue.

Comment: It sounds like your benchmark results are invalid because you are using different compilers and different compilation settings.  Sorry, you will have to do the benchmark over again.  And you ARE running processes in the background, it is unavoidable, the only question is "which processes".

Comment: I got the solution by compiling the same code with optimization flags in gcc compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Do you do any function calls in the loop (e.g. to functions defined in "math.h")?

If yes, the problem could be a less efficient implementation of these functions in the GNU library (used in Linux) compared to the Windows libraries.

Are you generating 32 or 64 bit executables? Comparing a 64 bit executable on one system and a 32 bit executable on the other one makes no sense!

You (normally) can run 32 bit executables under 64 bit Linux if you install the 32 bit runtime libraries or you compile statically. You always can run 32 bit executables under 64 bit Windows.

If you do not use function calls and 32/64 bit is also not an issue you could check if this is a compiler performance issue by doing the following:

- First isolate the loop into a single C file. This means: Move the loop into a function "test_loop()" and move this function to a separate C file.
- Especially when generating 64-bit executables the function should not have any arguments but all data in and out should be done via global variables.
- Get GCC for Windows and compile the file using the "-s" option (gcc -o loop.s -S loop.c). The result will be an assembler file.
- Ensure to compile 64 bit on Windows if you'll check against 64 bit Linux and to compile 32 bit on Windows if you'll check against 32 bit Linux
- Compile the whole program using GCC for Windows (gcc -o test.exe test.c loop.s) and make runtime measurements.
- Note: Under Windows, 32 bit, the C compiler adds underscores to all function names. Therefore the function will be named "_test_loop()" when using the assembler file under Linux. The same is true for global variable names (used by the assembler file). You'll have to adapt the remaining C file(s) for compilation under Linux. *When compiling 64 bit this is not the case.*
- Compile the program under Linux. Do not compile the C file containing the loop again but use the assembler file generated under Windows. Compare the runtime on Linux to the runtime on Windows
- Use the **same computer** for the runtime measurements; not two computers with "similar hardware"

If the runtime now is the same for both OSs then you see it is a compiler issue. You could use the Microsoft compiler to compile the file under Windows and use the object file under Linux if performance under Linux is required. Unfortunately Windows uses another object file format than Linux so the object file has to be converted (from COFF to ELF).

If the runtime is still faster under Windows then the problem *may* be an accurracy problem with the time measurement. Time measurements less then 100ms are often very unaccurrate. To check this you should create an outer loop running from 0 to 999 so that now three loops are nested. The time should now be 55 seconds compared to 25 seconds.

Comment: By setting optimization flag in gcc compiler, now i can get more speed to execute nested for loop within less time which is required..